# How can I delete table row values in pairs? For example, if either column is less than 0.01, how do I delete the row?

Tags: matlab

I have two sets of data from different instruments that have common X-variables (XThompsons) but various Y-variables (YCounts) due to various experimental conditions. The data resemble the example below:

```
[Table1]
XThompsons | YCounts (1) | YCounts (2) | YCounts (3) | .... | .... 
------------------------------------------------------------------

[Table2]
XThompsons | YCounts (1) | YCounts (2) | YCounts (3) | .... | .... 
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I have two sets of data that are like this, I have written a script to take a single Y-column information from Table1 and do some math to all Y-columns in Table2. However, when comparing two table columns if either column has a value of a specific threshold (0.10) I want to delete that value. In the example below I want to delete row 4 and row 6 because either column has a value containing 0.10 or less

```
XThompsons | Table1.YCounts(1) | Table2.YCounts(2)
--------------------------------------------------
     1             1.00                 0.50
     2             0.22                 0.12
     3             0.29                 0.14
     4             0.29                 0.09         (delete row)
     5             0.11                 0.49
     6             0.02                 0.83         (delete row)
```

How can I carry this out in Matlab? My current code is below; I convert each table row to an array first. How can I make it so that if Y < 0.10 delete the row?

```
datax = readtable('table1.xls'); % Instrument 1
datay = readtable('table2.xls'); % Instrument 2
SIDATA = [];

for idx=2:width(datay);

    % Read the indexed column of datax (instrument 1) then normalize to 1
    x = table2array(datax(:,idx));
    x = x ./ max(x);

    % Read indexed column of datay (instrument 2) and carry out loop
    for idy=2:width(datay);

        % Normalize y data to 1
        y = table2array(datay(:,idy));
        y = y ./ max(y);

        % Calculate similarity index (SI) at using the datax index for all collision energies for datay
        xynum = sum(sqrt(x) .* sqrt(y));
        xyden = sqrt(sum(x) .* sum(y)); 
        SIDATA(idy,idx) = (xynum/xyden);
    end

end
```

Help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: `datax=datax.*(datax>0.1);` This will element-wise multiply `datax` by the truth table for all `datax` that is greater than 0.1, so anything less than 0.1 will by multiplied by 0 and will therefore become 0. If this works for you, let me know and I'll repost at an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally when looping through and pruning values you want to increment from the end of the matrix back to one; this way, if you delete any rows, you don't skip. (If you delete row 2, then advance to row 3, you skip the data formerly in row 3).

To me, the easiest way to do this is that if all your data is in one matrix A, with columns Y1 Y2,

```
APruned = A((A(:,1) > 0.1) & (A(:,2) > 0.1),:)
```

This takes the A matrix, finds the rows where Y1 > 0.1, finds the rows where Y2 > 0.1, finds the overlap, and then outputs only the rows in A where both of these are true.

[You should read about logical indecies for more on this topic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

EDIT: It looks like you could also clean up your earlier code using element-wise operations;

```
A = [datax./max(datax) datay./max(datay)];
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: This is exactly the insight that I'm looking for! Will be reading up on coding matlab a bit more. It's been a bit difficult cause my training is as an analytical chemist but I deal with large datasets. I guess in grad school my advisor figured that we should just barrel through large sets of data by hand instead of using code (grad student = lots of time, industry professional = lots of money).